# Where do the auto-sitemap files get generated?

Tags: org-publish

I have the following blog site structure

```
~/my-org-site $ tree
.
├── build-site.el
├── build.sh
├── content
│   ├── index.org
│   ├── markdown_to_org.py
│   ├── org_posts
│   │   ├── post\ 1.org
│   │   ├── post\ 2.org
```

this is build-site.el

```
(require 'ox-publish)

(setq org-html-validation-link nil
      org-html-head-include-scripts nil
      org-html-head-include-default-style nil
      org-html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\"
        href=\"https://cdn.simplecss.org/simple.min.css\" />")
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      (list
       (list "my-org-site"
             :recursive t
             :base-directory "./content"
             :publishing-directory "./public"
             :publishing-function 'org-html-publish-to-html
             :with-author nil
             :with-creator t
             :with-toc t)
       (list "blog_posts"
             :recursive nil
             :auto-sitemap t
             :sitemap-filename "blog_posts.org"
             :sitemap-title "Posts"
             :base-directory "./content/org_posts"
             :publishing-directory "./public/posts"
             :publishing-function 'org-html-publish-to-html
             :with-author nil
             :with-creator t
             :with-toc t)
       ))

(org-publish-all t)

(message "Build Complete!")
```

When I build the site, it does indeed create the posts in the public directory. However I cannot find the "blog_posts.org" file. Where does this get created? When I try and do
`#+ include: content/blog_posts.org` on index.org for instance I get

```
Cannot include file /Users/alexmarshall/my-org-site/content/blog_posts.org
```

Which makes sense because I can't find the file. But yeah where does it get generated to?

Answer (score 1):

I found it in the content/org_posts directory. I was looking for it in the published directory but it gets put in content along with index.org.